# Set file modification time from the date string present in the filename

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sed, xargs

I'm restoring a number of archives with dates within their names, something along the lines of:

```
user-2018.12.20.tar.xz
user-2019.01.10.tar.xz
user-2019.02.25.tar.xz
user-2019.04.19.tar.xz
...
```

I want to set each file's modification date to match the date in their filename by piping the filenames to `touch` via `xargs` and using `replace-str` to set the dates.

`touch -m -t` will take a datetime in the format `[CCYYMMDDhhmm]`, but I'm having trouble substituting inline:

```
find . -name "*.xz" | xargs -I {} touch -m -t $(sed -e 's/\.tar\.xz//g; s/user-//g; s/\.//g; s/\///g; s/$/0000/g' {}) {}
```

Returns `touch: invalid date format ‘./user-2018.03.22.tar.xz’`, even though this:

```
find . -name "*.xz" | sed -e 's/\.tar\.xz//g; s/user-//g; s/\.//g; s/\///g; s/$/0000/g'
```

Returns properly-formatted dates, for example `201812200000`. Am I misusing command substitution in my replace string somehow?

**EDIT :** Yes, a simple script could do this no problem. But the question remains...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need `find`, `sed`, `xargs` or any third party tools, but just use the shell built-in regex capabilities to get the timestamp from the file

```
 for file in *.tar.xz; do
     [ -f "$file" ] || continue
     if [[ $file =~ ^user-([[:digit:]]+).([[:digit:]]+).([[:digit:]]+).tar.xz$ ]]; then
         dateStr="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}${BASH_REMATCH[2]}${BASH_REMATCH[3]}0000"
         touch -m -t "$dateStr"
     fi
 done
```

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that the command substitution will be evaluated once when you call `xargs`, not for each argument. You would need to spawn a shell for that:

```
find . -name "*.xz" \
  | xargs -I {} bash -c 'touch -m --date "$(sed -e "s/\.tar\.xz//;s/user-//g; s/\.//g; s/\///g;" <<< "$1")" "$1"' -- {}
```

Note: `xargs` is not needed because you can use the `-exec` option of `find`:

```
find . -name "*.xz" -exec bash -c 'touch -m --date "$(sed -e "s/\.tar\.xz//;s/user-//g; s/\.//g; s/\///g;" <<< "$1")" "$1"' -- {} \;
```

---

PS: A small for loop would be more readable:

```
for file in user-*.tar.xz ; do
    # remove prefix and suffix
    date=${file#user-}
    date=${date%.tar.xz}
    # replace dots by /
    date=${date//./\/}

    touch -m --date "${date}" "${file}"
done
```

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you (GNU parallel):

```
parallel --dryrun touch -m --date '{= s/[^0-9]//g =}' {} ::: *.xz
```

When happy that the commands are correct, then remove the `--dryrun` option.

Alternative:

```
parallel touch -m --date `{= s/user-//;s/\.tar\.xz//;s/\.//g =}' {} ::: *.xz
```